# Bison %token-table alternatives in c++ parser?

Tags: c++, bison, bisonc++

I'm learning [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Decl-Summary.html) in generating c++ parser.

Since `%token-table` is obsolescent, is there any alternatives to get the name from token integer value in c++ parser?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `yysymbol_name()`, described in the [manual section on syntax error reporting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Syntax-Error-Reporting-Function.html).

The C++ API apparently has a similar [method on the parser context object](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/C_002b_002b-Parser-Context.html), called `symbol_name`. (See [this future question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68028077/1566221) for more information about C++.)

Comment: Hi, since I'm using Bison to generate a c++ parser, I didn't find any API named `yysymbol_name()`. Does it support c++ ?

Comment: @linrongbin: you shouldn't tag with two language tags unless you are prepared to accept an answer in either language. I would be very surprised if the C++ API doesn't have that feature but since I hardly ever use the C++ API, I don't know what it is.

Comment: Otoh, it didn't take long to find by looking through the manual. You should try that :-)