# Bison C++ get name of token - yytname_ is private

Tags: c++, bison, bisonc++

I'm attempting to get the name of a token in C++ Bison:
E.g. `%token <int> TPLUS "+" TMINUS "-" TMUL "*" TDIV "/"`

However in the C++ variant of Bison, `%token-table` does not do anything.

I have noticed that there is a token mapping in the generated bison code:  `const char* const parser::yytname_[];` however it is private.

Does anyone have any idea of how to get the names of these tokens in C++ Bison?  Is this even possible using the C++ variant?

I know this question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63573294/bison-token-table-alternatives-in-c-parser.), but there is no accepted answer.

Using version 3.4.3

Comment: My bison manual doesn't mention any C++ restriction for %token-table.  If you're sure it doesn't do anything, it might be worthwhile asking the project what the restriction is, and how you're supposed to use it.  From the documentation, I would expect it produce the same global array it does under C.

Comment: Doesn't [`symbol_name`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#index-symbol_005fname-on-parser) give you what you need?

Comment: @rici Updated. thanks

Comment: @rici Theres no symbol_name functions in the generated code

Comment: @Tom: I think you need quite a recent version of Bison, preferably the one which corresponds to that documentation (3.7.6). I don't remember exactly when that interface was added, but it wasn't long ago.

Comment: Also, you need to %define parse.error to custom, detailed or verbose (and verbose changes the return type of symbol_name).

Comment: @rici Upgrading Bison to the latest version solved the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: Cool. In the meantime, I wrote up an answer with what I discovered looiking through the various C++ templates in the bison source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, ensure that you have a recent version of Bison (I believe the minimum is v3.6, but the v3.7 versions have several useful bug fixes).

That will generate a static member function named `symbol_name` with one of the following prototypes. Note that `token_symbol_kind is an  *internal* token number, not the value produced by the scanner. (See below)

```cpp
const char* yy::parser::symbol_name(token_symbol_kind)  (1)
std::string yy::parser::symbol_name(token_symbol_kind)  (2)

(1) if %define parse.error custom|detailed
(2) if %define parse.error verbose
```

If the option `parse.error` is not defined, then you can still get the `symbol_name` definition by using the deprecated `%token-table` directive, or if you arrange for `#define YYDEBUG` to be inserted in the generated code (see the `-d` flag, for example). I have no idea why the return type differs depending on the definition of `parse.error`.

As noted, the argument to `symbol_name` is a bison internal token number, rather than the token type returned by the scanner. You can get the internal token number for a token type using the `parser` member class `by_kind`, with an expression like `yy::parser::by_kind(yy::parser::token::«token-type-name»).type_get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're bison is the latest version (3.7.3) in my case. The name of a token can be derived by:

```
std::cout << yy::parser::symbol_name(yy::parser::by_kind(yy::parser::token::TPLUS).type_get()) << std::endl;
```

Where `y::parser::token::TPLUS` is your token.